# Ставится ли точка перед скобкой?

Tags: пунктуация

Закрались сомнения относительно того, нужна ли точка перед скобкой, если внутри скобки заключено предложение, которое начинается с большой буквы. Всегда ставила точку.

А как быть в случае, если в конце статьи, к примеру, есть запись в виде "(Окончание в следующем номере)"?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По логике, предыдущее предложение должно окончиться точкой.Предложение в скобках относится ко всему тексту, а не к предыдущему предложению, поэтому в скобках пишем с большой буквы и  в конце предложения тоже ставим точку перед закрывающей скобкой. Это касается ремарок и вставных предложений, как у Вас: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm

Например: Она была уже далеко.(Окончание в следующем номере.)